# Getting HashMap of data from database using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 4 entities and 4 tables in database for each of them. They are:

- Company
- Contract
- Package
- PackageCategory

Between them are defined relations:

- Company - OneToMany - Contract
- Contract - OneToOne - Package
- Package - OneToOne - PackageCategory

And inverse:

- Contract - OneToOne - Company
- Package - OneToMany - Contract
- PackageCategory - OneToMany - Package

My database looks like:[image]

My question is how make `HashMap<String, List<Company>` where key will be from `package_categories.name` column, and value for that key will be list of all companies which have contract which belongs to package, and where that package belongs to category which name is equal to key? 
In one list Company should appear only once.

Comment: I think the only way is to iterate over all entries of a big select and collect them by yourself. So I dont think JDBC helps you here. Or you can select the tables separately and join them in Java - but dont make loops with multiple calls. The foreign keys must somehow be part of the select or you must join them by SQL. Solution may depend on the amount of companies etc.

Comment: What you want is to query for a specific result. You would probably be best advised to do this via JPA Criteria API (or if you are more of a fluent fan QueryDSL and Jinq) that would enable you to write a typesafe query. Do not write JPQL or SQL queries.